# i got a error when when connecting websocket with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, websocket

i am trying to run this 
[example](http://clintberry.com/2013/angular-js-websocket-service/)

i got a error mesasge like this

`Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'MyApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument. http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.14/$injector/nomod?p0=MyApp
return new Error(message);`

anyone suggest how can i implement event handling in angularjs with websockets.

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle? or check the url :http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a module to use it... so you have to have this piece of code

```
angular.module('MyApp', [/*dependencies or empty array*/])
```

somewhere in your script - somewhere means before any other `angular.module('MyApp').whatever...` code